# Is there a way to disable notification for WhatsApp except from specific people?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

Someone told me there's a way to disable all notifications from WhatsApp except for messages from specific people.

How can I do this? (I own a Pixel 3)

Comment: If you want to receive everything from this group of people and ignore others, then turn on "Do not disturb" mode & just include your desired people as exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to achieve it is the following:

1. Open WhatsApp
2. On the main screen, long-press to select a contact
3. After the first contact is selected, tap on all the contacts you don't want to receive notifications from. You will have to select the contacts one by one because there is no "Select all contacts" button (if there are hundreds or thousands, then good luck selecting them)
4. Press the muted speaker icon. A pop-up will appear asking for how long the contacts should be muted. Select the time (don't enable "Show notifications" just in case).

The selected contacts will be muted, their notifications won't be shown except only those that were not selected. Note that if a muted contact calls, you will still receive the notification.

Comment: Not very practical for what I wanted, but I realize there probably doesn't exist a more practical way. Thanks!

Comment: In 2022 it's possible to select all contacts after selecting the first. Then you can unselect those that you don't want to mute.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround only to not hear sounds from all contacts except from a specific contact is to set the notification tone as "None" in whatsapp notification settings. Now go to the specific contact on whatsapp and change their notification sound from default (none) to a required sound. This will not stop showing notifications on your display though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable notifications for specific group except from specific people:

1. Navigate to a group or person.
2. Select group/person by long-press.
3. Press three dots menu.
4. Press *Group info* (if you have selected group) or *View contact* (if you have selected person).
5. Press *Custom notifications*.
6. Tick the *Use custom notifications* checkbox and start customising the notifications for this specific group/person.

You should set *None* sound for *Notification tone* for the group to effectively disable notifications for the group and then you should set custom sound for all persons in the group whom you want to receive notifications for.

Comment: I also think this should work, but may take more steps than [another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216178/44325).

Comment: This works perfectly, and it works both ways: you can *disable* notifications for a single contact (or group), or, if you've disabled *all* group notifications, you can *enable* notifications for a single contact (or group).

Comment: This does not work. It seems that `Notification tone` for the group has higher priority than `Notification tone` for particular contact(s).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

The basic M.O. of any "social media" including WhatsApp is that you are not supposed to be free to choose when and with whom you want to communicate even if you get the illusion of that.

Comment: Clearly incorrect.  The accepted answer gives one way of doing it and I can think of others.  Besides, any social medium forcing crap upon you is violating GDPR.

Comment: Actually this is answer is correct because the accepted answer specifies how to *disable* notifications from *specific* contacts - not to *disable by default* and enable only specific ones.